# What's the next "recursion" here?

Tags: parametric, recursive-algorithms

Plotting a single 3d helix is

x = cos(t);
y = sin(t);
z = t;

From this equation:

x = [R + a cos(\omega t)] cos t

y = [R + a cos(\omega t)] sin t

z = h t + a sin(omega t)

[image]

Comes the awesome helix-within-an-helix.

How can I figure out the equation for *n* amount of "recursive" helixes-within-helixes?

Comment: I think the thing to do is: Given a space curve $\mathbf{R}(t)$, find the space curve $H[\mathbf{R}](t)$ which winds as a helix (with given radius and torsion) around $\mathbf{R}(t)$. If you can find that, then iterating that to get helices upon helices seems like it should be evident.

Comment: Can you give me one more clue?

Comment: Just came across this older question: [Helix in a helix](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/470556/137524)