# Helix around Helix around Circle

Tags: geometry, 3d, curves, parametric, parametrization

I'm trying to find the **parametric equations** for a **helix around a helix around a circle** ([helix on helix on circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StmW7.png))
That is: I would like to start with a circle, add a helix around it and a helix around the helix.([See video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_ww0-RrKFw))

I'm ok even if the second helix is not perfectly orthogonal to the first helix as long as we can have a simpler parametrization.
I'm ok also if the curve represents a helix around a helix around a helix.

I know the helix around a helix around an axis is quite easy but I was not able to find a solutions for this case.
I'm interested in this parametric curve as a way to represent time and I would like to write a program to show data attached to that curve.

**Edit:** I already know the parametric equations of a helix around a torus:

$$x(t) = (R+ r\cos(nt))  \cos(t)$$

$$y(t) = (R+ r\cos(nt))  \sin(t)$$

$$z(t) = s t + r  \sin(nt)$$

where $R$ is the radius of the torus

$r$ is the radius of the helix

$n$ is the winding number

$s$ vertical velocity ($0$ if we want a closed curve).

What I'm looking for is the next level helix on top of that.

Comment: I totally endorse Ted Shifrin's answer as the definitive method for parametrizing these curves. I link to three older threads simply to connect all four [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461547/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470538/11619), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/946460/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: You are looking at a curve spiraling at a constant rate about a torus. Start by finding parametric equations of a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus). Now make the two angles linear functions of $t$. It appears you want one to go much faster than the other, so that suggests how you should relate those linear functions.

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, you want a curve that spirals around a given space curve. The way to do that is to take an orthonormal basis for the *normal* plane to the curve at each point and go around a circle as you move along the curve. In particular, take the *Frenet frame* $T,N,B$ for the curve, parametrized say by $\alpha(s)$. Now consider $$\alpha(s)+\cos\theta(s)N(s)+\sin\theta(s)B(s)$$ where $\theta$ is a linear function of $s$. (If you don't know about Frenet frames, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) or my differential geometry text, linked in my profile. It's most convenient to work with arclength-parametrized curves $\alpha(s)$, but the chain rule will do the heavy lifting for you if they're not.)

Comment: I'm looking for a curve that spirals around the curve you describe (I already know the parametric equations for the curve you described).

Comment: Your question really needs to be made clearer. So you want a curve spiraling around the curve in your picture. Helix is not going to be an accurate word, because it has technical mathematical meaning. But I will edit appropriately.

Comment: I understand what you say about the Frenet frame T,N,B, what I was trying to ask is: 
is there a direct parametric representation of that curve?

Comment: I just gave you a "direct parametrization."  You have the spiraling curve on the torus — that's $\alpha$, and then you have to calculate its Frenet frame and do as I said. Is it a simple, elegant formula? Um, NO. This isn't too hard to do in Mathematica or other CAS, but not much fun to do by hand.

Comment: OK, I understand, I hoped it was possible to calculate everything and get an explicit formula but you're right, your formula will work fine especially in a program. thx.
I was hoping for a formula that gives x(t), y(t), z(t) using t ... I thought it was possibile to generalize in some way the mechanism and find a pattern.

Comment: Of course, what I'm suggesting will give an explicit formula. I just will not work it out by hand. If you find a superior solution, you should post it. Otherwise, I think you need to do what I suggested and take my answer as the answer. :P

Comment: Ok, got it! Does Wolfram Alpha (or other programs) have explicit commands to calculate 
Frenet vectors?

Comment: Not that I know of. Having taught differential geometry dozens of times, I wrote my own Mathematica program to do so. And others. If you have access to Mathematica (as opposed to Wolfram Alpha), I'm happy to share a notebook with you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I installed and used Mathematica when at the university but I don't have it anymore. I think I'll just write some code and forget about the explicit formula. Thank you.

Comment: Just to let you know that I was able to use Frenet vectors and Rodrigues' Rotation Formula https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RodriguesRotationFormula.html
to get this:
http://www.guzman.it/3/toro.html
that was part of something I'm working on

Comment: That looks cool. I never knew Rodrigues' formula per se, but it's just an application of the change of basis theorem (which I know all too well). Well done! By the way, you should accept the answer at this point :P