# parameterization of helix of a helix of a helix

Tags: geometry, curves

I am trying to write the parameterization of a helix made up of a helix which is also made up of a helix. I have the parameterization of a helix of a helix.

x=(R+a*cos(t))cos(t/w)

y=(R+a*cos(t))sin(t/w)
z=h*t+a*sin(t/w)

I have tried to further extend this to a third slinky by adding the third radius and multiplying x,y,y by the same trig functions that are progressing at a slower rate.

cos(t/10*w)

sin(t/10*w)

sin(t/1w)

I would appreciate and help with this problem

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helix in a helix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470538/helix-in-a-helix)