# Equation of a 3D spiral

Tags: geometry

I want to know if a 3D spiral, that looks like this:

[image: Spiral]

can be approximated to any sort of geometric primitive that can be described with a known equation, like some sort of twisted cylinder I suppose.

Thanks

Comment: I plotted @abnry's function `x(t)=radius * cos(t), y(t)=radius * sin(t), z(t)=const * t` in Three.js: https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/01b57075b79ad306220d752bccfe2375

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/461637/11619).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Equation for a [helix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix):
$$x(t) = R \cos t, \quad y(t) = R \sin(t), \quad z(t) = at.$$

If you actually want a surface, then use the above to write
$$(x-x(z/a))^2+(y-y(z/a))^2 = r^2$$
or
$$(x-R \cos(z/a))^2+(y-R \sin(z/a))^2 = r^2$$
where $r$ is the radius of the "tube" and $R$ is the winding radius. In your particular picture you will have $a >> 1$ and $r, R = o(1)$.

Comment: Does he just want a line or a shape with volume?

Comment: I have him both. The first is just the line. The second is surface thought of as a circle whose position moves depending on z.

Comment: Thanks, yep - wanted to be able to dictate the width of the "tube".

Comment: The implicit equation is bad because a helix is twisted so the circular section is not parallel to the $xy$-plane.  But for helicoid, we can have an implicit equation: $x\sin \frac{z}{b}=y\cos \frac{z}{b}$ and for torus $(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}=4a(x^{2}+y^{2})$.

Comment: I agree with @NgChungTak. The circular cross-sections should IMO be orthogonal to the curve - not parallel to the $xy$-plane. If $a$ is not large, then the distortion becomes clear (props for observing the need to have $a>>1$ though). See [my old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/461637/11619).

Comment: Your switching between parametric and explicit equations is confusing. Is there a way to use only a parametric equation?

Answer (score 5):

These are the parametric equations of a corkscrew
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x&=a \cos(\theta)\\
y&=a \sin(\theta)\\
z&=a  \theta\tan(\alpha)  \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Where $a$ is constant, the radius of the cylinder, and $\alpha$ is the constant angle made by the tangent with the $x, y$ plane.

Answer (score 5):

The tube thickness can also be varied as a function of any desired parameter ( radius, axial length, theta, arc length along tube etc.), the following image is that of of a helix on a cone. Code line is in Mathematica.

[image: HelixOnCone]